# SWING - Different colors in same JPanel

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jpanel

I'm brand new with Swing and I'm trying to display one JPanel with some figures inside it. I draw them overriding the method PaintComponent from the class Graphics but i would like each one of them has different colours. My problem is that I can only set the color of the JPanel and the the colours of all the figures inside are the same.

Does anybody know how can I do it? If its possible without creating one JPanel for every picture. Thanks!

EDIT: Here is a piece of my code:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){ 
    super.paintComponent(g); 
    g.setColor(Color.RED); 
    g.fillOval(524, 45, 34, 34); 
    g.fillOval(615, 45, 34, 34); 
    g.fillOval(396, 233, 34, 34);  
    g.fillOval(746, 233, 34, 34); 
}
```

Of course like this I can't make the difference between the Circles, there is another way to draw them with differences between them?

Comment: Please help us help you by showing your pertinent code and showing what you've tried to do to solve it, or just what confuses you in your code attempt. Best if you can create and post a [mcve] or [sscce](http://sscce.org). Please check out these worthwhile links.

Comment: you can use `setColor(Color c)` method to set different colors

Comment: Also, if you haven't done so, factor your code so that the figures have their own logical class, a class that holds color information and that knows how to draw itself, and then within paintComponent, tell each figure that the JPanel displays to paint itself by calling the figure's `public void draw(Graphics g)` passing in the Graphics parameter.

Comment: Please post your code as an edit to your original question, not as a comment, since the information is too important to be buried in comments, and comments don't allow you to format code. Also, and again, please read the links I've provided since your code posted does not appear to be enough of what we need.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, the refactoring is a good idea, but it may be overkill for what he's doing. Sounds like he's just learning now, so a good experiment would be to get _something_ drawing before breaking it down to full OO.

Comment: @Frecklefoot: perhaps you're right. I'm just thinking down the line when he wants to *change* the oval's color when the user clicks it. Original poster: you're also going to want to avoid using "magic numbers", like the numbers that you have in your fillOval method calls. If you make them variables and not hard-coded numbers, your program will become much more flexible and powerful.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I know it, thanks, I only was trying to do it visually for myself and after apply in my code :)

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: you are absolutely correct again. Down the line. Hard-coded numbers are fine for PoCs, though. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an easy example of a paintComponent method

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(new Color(5,5,5));
    g.fillRect(0,0,100,100);
    g.setColor(Color.Green);
    g.drawRoundRect(30,30,20,20,5,5);
    g.setColor(new Color(200,200,200));
    g.setFont(new Font("Eras Bold ITC", Font.BOLD, 150));
    g.drawString("hi",25,25);
}
```

Tip:

```
revalidate();
repaint();
```

will repaint every component of the frame

Comment: Thanks, forgot the annotation.

Comment: And the `protected`. Avoid making code more visible then it has to be. 1+

Comment: Thank you, i didn't know that i can do that! :) It works perfectly!

Comment: would a paint method really have to be protected? I get why protected is better and safer for a lot of methods, but i think making the paint method public would be fine.

Comment: Nick: does the method have to be protected? No, of course not, but just as a matter of good practice, one should avoid promoting visibility if this promotion is not needed. The whole raison d'etre for OOP design is to reduce complexity, including cyclomatic complexity, as this reduces risk of bugs, and public methods and fields contribute greatly to increasing this property. Yes I may be being overly strict here, but I like to encourage good practice when posting answers for newbies.

Comment: Nick, if you want to get @paxinco's attention in comment, append an `@` prior to his name. e.g., `@nickzoum`.

Comment: Done! Sorry for the inconveniences!